# requesting php image files in a loop

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a php file that produces a graph, populated through the answers of 4 sql statements, in another php file i have a simple loop that requests the image by posting a variable through session to a variable nested within the sql of the image file.

i have checked that the 'sent' variable is iterating through my loop... but the problem is that if i want to itterate by 2 the 2 images i get are of the last result instead of graph1, graph2, i get graph2, graph2...

is their something i missing? Please any help - very new to PHP thanks :)
heres the loop;

```
<?php
session_start();

for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    $_SESSION['question'] = $i;
    ?>
    <div id="apDiv1"><img src="round.php"></div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure I fully follow, the code confused me.  Sounds like you are overwriting the value in the loop.  Maybe you need an additional dimension on the array (session?) you are pushing the value to?...  `$_SESSION['question'][] = $i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is their something i missing?

Yes, sessions in PHP are blocking. That means while your script in question runs, the `round.php` script does not run. It will wait until the script in question has finished.

*More correctly:* even longer. The output must even go to the browser first.

Then it provides you the graphs as images. The `$_SESSION` variable then is longtime to 2 already.

Instead pass a query parameter (`$_GET` parameter), `$_SESSION` does not work here.

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
{     
    ?><div id="apDiv1"><img src="round.php?graph=<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><?php
}

?>
```

Comment: how would i pass $get parameter though within this loop?

Comment: @user1775578: I named that `graph`. In graph.php this will become `$_GET['graph']` if set. See http://php.net/language.variables.external

Comment: you are a legend :) Thanks very mush it works wahoo lol

Answer (score 0):

The loop isn't effecting your session setting, if you ignore the html output for a second:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++){
  $_SESSION['question'] = $i;
}
```

and

```
$_SESSION['question'] = 2;
```

Are equivalent.  You are just overwriting the same value twice.

Comment: i get it now the image file has changed to graph 2, the loop is just showing the image by the correct number....